# Webview in xcode swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am pretty new to Xcode and swift, which is why I am asking for your help. I have tried to make simpel webview application, but after trying a dozen different codes from other creators, my projects does still not seem to work. Said in a different way: I want my app to go to a webview with a certain address after you have pressed a button.

But that is not the only thing that I want. After opening a certain webpage, I would also like to get the url parameters and save them in the app, then close the webview (or go to a new page).

I do not expect you to write all that code for me, but I would like to hear if anyone know somebody who have already done this, or have some parts of the code

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please share what you have done or tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

1. First of all you should create your `UIButton` via `Storyboard` or `code` inside your first viewController.
2. Next you should create a `WKWebView`, for this one you should import `WebKit` framework. then make a http request using `load` method of that webView.
3. Present next  viewController containing webView. or load webView inside your first viewController.

---

### Swift 5

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var websiteAddress: String {
      return "https://mohamadreza.com"
    }

    lazy var someButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.someButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("Go to Webview", for: .normal)
        return button
    }()

    lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let web = WKWebView.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let url = URL.init(string: self.websiteAddress)!
        let request = URLRequest.init(url: url)
        web.load(request)
        return web
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addButton()
    }

    func addButton() {
        self.view.addSubview(self.someButton)
        self.someButton.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.someButton.center = self.view.center
    }

    @objc func someButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.goToWebview()
    }

    func goToWebview() {
        let controller = UIViewController()
        controller.view.addSubview(self.webView)
        self.present(controller,animated: true)
    }

}
```

### Playground Support

if you want to test this code just import PlaygroundSupport
and at the last line out of ViewController class assing liveView to `ViewController` object.

at top:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
```

at last:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is really useful. As I understand your code, I should just be able to copy all the code into my ViewController file and then run the project, right? But when I do so, I just get a blank screen in the simulator.

Comment: it is not the way you should do, you should put it in multiple viewController. a viewController who controls a web view should be diffrent in your case ... , i provided how you should do it, you can use them in your real code.